# ray tracing: "size" of the field of depth

Tags: raytracing

How do I actually define the depth of the field, that is, the range of z-values where my objects would be in focus. That is, I want objects with `z`-coords in `[f-w,f+w]` to be in focus (camera coords), where `f` is the focal length and `w` is some predefined constant.

The way I do it now is I find a primary ray from lens center to `P` (point on the focal plane, `z=-f`), then shoot rays from random points `L` on the lens to `P`.

What I am seeing is that the implicit value `w` is very small, so there is a very visible band  where things are in focus, and everything near it and further is blurred. Now, I could play with `d` (distance from lens to image plane) and aperture values to make a specific scene look OK, but I wanted to see some maths on how to solve this issue properly.

I've looked at several ray tracing books and they all skirt this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else will look, a 1995 paper by Kolb, Mitchel, Hanrahan - `A Realistic Camera Model for Computer Graphics` describes a lens model of thickness `t` and how to control the depth of the field itself.

[Link to paper](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/camera/lens.ps)